# How is the rate of evolution of a language measured?

Tags: evolution, vocabulary, glottochronology

Have linguists measured the rate of evolution of a language by analyzing the rate of change of the language's words' usages over time? Is there a term for this sort of measurement?

For example, suppose a language has N words (or usages of a word) W<sub>0</sub>, W<sub>1</sub>, W<sub>1</sub>, …, W<sub>n</sub>. For each W<sub>i</sub> one could associate a rate of increase or decrease R<sub>i</sub> (e.g., determined with [Google's N-grams](http://books.google.com/ngrams) or, better, using some other smarter means which can distinguish usages). Then the rate of change of the language could be estimated by taken some kind of average of all the W<sub>i</sub>.

Comment: It is called glottochronology.

Comment: What do you mean by "usage"? For example "meat" was formerly used broadly to refer to food, but now is used primarily to refer to animal flesh as food. "Sick" is now used (*qua* slang term) to mean something good.

Comment: @user6726 "meat" as animal flesh, "meat" as food, "sick" as good, and "sick" as ill would all be different Wᵢ's.

Comment: @amegnunsen That would be the study, but I'm looking for a term for the statistical measure of a language's evolution.

Comment: It is called Rate of replacement and is symbolised by L. The formula is L = 2ln(r), where r is called Glottochronological constant.

Comment: It is not known whether r exists or not. I.e, whether the rate of lexical replacement is a constant or not is unknown, and what the value or r ought to be in any particular context is usually not known either.

Comment: Related question: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/17409/what-is-the-difference-between-linguistic-distance-and-lexical-distance

Comment: Indeed, it seems more realistic that languages change at a different rates and this rate varies depending on the time, but this formula is still a good modelling, we just have to adapt it.

Comment: There are too many factors at play in different situations to make this a "measurable thing". And what is rate? Fast, slow, medium? I mean...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Robert B. Lees devised a "glottochronological constant" in:

- Robert B. Lees, “[The Basis of Glottochronology](https://isidore.co/misc/Physics%20papers%20and%20books/Zotero/storage/CQSZ6LBH/Lees%20-%201953%20-%20The%20Basis%20of%20Glottochronology.pdf),” *Language* 29, no. 2 (1953): 113–27.

Abstract:

> It is shown that a linguistic dating system can be set up on the basis of several explicit assumptions about morpheme decay. Thirteen sets of data, presented in partial justification of these assumptions, serve as a basis for calculating a universal constant to express the average rate of retention k of the basic-root-morphemes: k = 0.8048 ± 0.0176 per millennium, with a confidence limit of 90%. Finally an expression is derived for the sampling-error to be expected in the calculated time-depths of related dialects.

Comment: The assumption of a glottochronological constant is challenged by many linguists, Daniel Nettle argues that language evolution is faster paced for small speech communities, see also this answer https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/20971/language-change-over-distance/20975#20975

Comment: I doubt that small speech communities evolve more rapidly. On contrary, they are more conservative and even more if they are isolated.